# What is best node.js cluster?

Tags: node.js, nginx, cluster-computing

There is a cluster module in node http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.19/api/cluster.html

But I found some other implementations like this one https://github.com/learnboost/cluster

What is the best, who is experienced?

Other question,

Is it necessary to use nginx in production? If so, why? How many simultaneous connections can be handled by single modern multicore server with node, 100K, 200k?

Thanx!

Comment: 100k simultaneous connections seems quite a high figure; a sustained load of 100k/sec connections would result in 144 million requests per day, which probably shouldn't be handled by a single-server single-process application.

Comment: no millions requests :) permanent connections, socket.io etc. for real-time updates, chat apps, so on

Answer (score 9):

1. The cluster module from https://github.com/learnboost/cluster is only available for Node v0.2.x and v0.4.x, while the official cluster module is baked into the Node core since v0.6.x. Note that the API will change for v0.8.x (which is around the corner).
   So you should use the latest version of Node, with Cluster built in.
2. NGiNX is faster for serving static files, but other than that I don't see any solid reason to use it. If you want a reverse proxy something like HAProxy is better (or you can use a Node solution like node-http-proxy or bouncy).
3. Unless you are using a "Hello World" example in production, you cannot accurately predict how many simultaneous connection can be handled. Normally a single Node process can handle thousand of concurrent connections.

Resources:

- https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
- https://github.com/substack/bouncy